# Consolidating columns by the number before the decimal point in the column name

Tags: pandas, dataframe

I have the following dataframe (three example columns below):

```
import pandas as pd
array = {'25.2': [False, True, False], '25.4': [False, False, True], '27.78': [True, False, True]}
df = pd.DataFrame(array)


    25.2    25.4    27.78
0   False   False   True
1   True    False   False
2   False   True    True
```

I want to create a new dataframe with consolidated columns names, i.e. add 25.2 and 25.4 into 25 new column. If one of the values in the separate columns is True then the value in the new column is True.

Expected output:

```
      25     27
0   False   True
1   True    False
2   True    True
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use `rename()`+`groupby()`+`sum()`:

```
df=(df.rename(columns=lambda x:x.split('.')[0])
      .groupby(axis=1,level=0).sum().astype(bool))
```

OR

In 2 steps:

```
df.columns=[x.split('.')[0] for x in df]
#OR
#df.columns=df.columns.str.replace(r'\.\d+','',regex=True)
df=df.groupby(axis=1,level=0).sum().astype(bool)
```

output:

```
    25      27
0   False   True
1   True    False
2   True    True
```

**Note:** If you have `int` columns then you can use `round()` instead of `split()`

Answer (score 1):

Another way:

```
>>> df.T.groupby(np.floor(df.columns.astype(float))).sum().astype(bool).T

    25.0   27.0
0  False   True
1   True  False
2   True   True
```